# Counting number of iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I know that the code is executed 8 times. But, is the condition checked 8 times or 9 times?

```
for num in range(2, 10):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("Found an even number", num)
        continue
    print("Found a number", num)
```

Comment: `8` times, (10-2)

Comment: You print either `"Found a number"` or `"Found an even number"` each iteration. You always get exactly one message per iteration, and the `if` condition decides which message is printed. Since you get eight messages, the `if` condition is executed eight times. If it was evaluated a ninth time, you’d get a ninth message.

Comment: Which "it" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

**for**: It is checked or evaluated as many + 1 times the for condition is defined

**if**: It is checked or evaluated as many times the for condition is defined.

Check this as follows:

> Assign→[Check→Runbody→Increment]∗→Check→Exit

Answer (score 0):

The program will loop through 8 times. Because of the `if` and `continue` different `print` statements are executed

```
In [51]: loop_count = 0

In [52]: for num in range(2, 10):
    ...:     loop_count+=1
    ...:     print(loop_count)
    ...:     if num % 2 == 0:
    ...:         print("Found an even number", num)
    ...:         continue
    ...:     print("Found a number", num)
    ...:
1
Found an even number 2
2
Found a number 3
3
Found an even number 4
4
Found a number 5
5
Found an even number 6
6
Found a number 7
7
Found an even number 8
8
Found a number 9
```

Answer (score 0):

The range object is checked 9 times. The first 8 times it returns the numbers 2 through 9 (8 numbers in all). On the 9th check the range object hits 10, hits its end condition, and raises `StopIteration`. The `for` swallows that exception and exits the loop.

If we iterated the range object in a `while` loop with our own counter, we see it in action

```
>>> count = 1
>>> range_iter = iter(range(2,10))
>>> while True:
...     print(count)
...     count += 1
...     x = next(range_iter)
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of Iteration will be 8 because you starting iteration from 2 as you mention in **range(2,10). Because range(starting point, ending point)**